# Как не показывать toast, когда приложения свернута

Tags: android, android-toast

Как не показывать toast, когда приложения свернута? ситуация в следующем, есть сервис к-ый работает, при развернутом состояние он возвращает тост при возникновении ошибки, но при свернутом состояние показывать пост, как сделать так что бы пользователь не увидел данный тост, а то выскакивает поверх других приложении

Comment: Только не говорите, что ваш сервис хранит ссылку на активити :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Activity есть onPause и onResume, там и следует реализовать передачу его состояния в Service, можно просто публичным статическим полем в классе Service, а в нужном методе проверка, если true, то Toast.

Comment: Никаких статических полей! Надо отключаться и подключаться снова к сервису. Т.е. делать `binding service`.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Объясните зачем.

Comment: Потому что так правильно. Примерно как во втором ответе.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Нет, так неправильно, а правильно - через статическое поле.

Answer (score -1):

Если Вы используете Bind'инг в своих активити, и для 
**bindService** используете событие onStart(), а для 
**unbindService** - onStop(), в таком случае довольно просто отследить состояние приложения в сервисе:

```
public class SomeService extends Service{
    private onForeground = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        onForeground = true;
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
        onForeground = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        onForeground = false;    
        return true;
    }

    private void showToast(String toastText){
        if(onForeground)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```